# Detect model in AR and make it invisible. Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I need detect static model in AR (chair for example) and make it invisible.
Is it possible to make with Unity? Any example?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXTcufnrsoY - something like this. Thanks.

Comment: This looks more like a green screen kind of video overlay using a static picture of the background and overlay it on the detected object...

Comment: I think this could help you : Vuforia Smart Terrain
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HV7Do1latBM